# How do i create a listview that displays a YouTube playlist with YouTube API

Tags: java, android, listview, parsing, youtube-api

i'm trying to create a simple android application that displays in a listview, a specific YouTube playlist. Can anybody help me? I'm just learning how to use APIs!

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't type of a question for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achive this you should have a valid google account.

First go to google youtube api.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests

There you can find all available api calls.

So you can invoke that api using your youtube access token. all the required steps are there in the api documentation.

In android make a rest api call and get the response as json or xml then decode it and populate your listview.

This is a good tutorial for begin your work.

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/